# WooCommerce shared categories

Tags: categories, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am working on a WooCommerce site where different electronics products are sold. A Product can be either a used or a new product. There are different categories e.g. Refrigerator, Freezer, Microwave oven, Heater etc.
Customer wants the users to be able to select based on whether user want to see/buy a new product or an old product and then choose from different categories mentioned above.

Should Used & New be parent category types where I will create the same categories e.g. Freezer, Refrigerator, oven etc as subcategories for each category or how should I approach it?

I am using Woodmart theme in case it matters.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: It's really down to your preference. I would suggest having a single product category might be easier to maintain, as long as you set up a custom taxonomy for condition (New or Used) and let visitors filter by either New or Used.

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine for the comment. I agree multiple categories of the same name doesn't seem to be the right way. Can I use that custom taxonomy in the filters when a user visits the Shop page? Do you recommend any plugin or it's better to code it myself?

Comment: Please note that plugin recommendations are off-topic on this stack. But taxonomies are basically made to filter posts - whether coded yourself or facilitated by a third-party plugin, you can certainly add an interactive filter control to your shop page.